Nut (upsd) connection refused
I have two Ubuntu servers in one subnetwork, 192.168.0.0/24.

192.168.0.10 - Baremetal server, Ubuntu 24.04 (x86_64)
192.168.0.11 - RPI, Ubuntu 24.04 (aarch64)

I have installed the nut server on RPI. My nutd
nut.conf:
MODE=netserver at 192.168.0.11 and MODE=netclient 192.168.0.10
upsd.conf
LISTEN 127.0.0.1 3493
LISTEN 192.168.0.11 3493

upsmon.conf
MONITOR ups@192.168.0.11 1 admin mypass master

ups.conf
[ups]
        driver = usbhid-ups
        port = auto
        offdelay = 90
        ondelay = 5


The service nut-monitor is running on 192.168.0.11 without problem, but on 192.168.0.10 logs:
 UPS [ups@192.168.0.11]: connect failed: Connection failure: no route to the host

upsc also cannot connect from 192.168.0.10, but is perfectly working on 192.168.0.11.
For testing purposes, I`m disabling UFW on both servers.
hosts.deny and host.allow are clean on both servers.
Also, ports are filtered from 10 and open from 11.
10 $ nmap 192.168.0.11 -p 3493
Host is up (0.00065s latency).

PORT     STATE    SERVICE
3493/tcp filtered nut


11 $ nmap 192.168.0.11 -p 3493
Host is up (0.00025s latency).
PORT     STATE SERVICE
3493/tcp open  nut 

Where can I find a problem, and fix it?
